# VS Code theme editing for flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When we code for flutter apps VS code shows the widget name after the parenthesis ( The red marked text in the image). Now it's color is grey and is irritating to my eyes. I want to reduce the opacity of the specified texts. But I don' know how to do that. I got a link on how to edit the color theme,but I couldn't find the proper way to do that. [image]

The link I got : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User key shortcut (Ctrl + ,) then on Top-Right Corner there is File icon click on  that to open settings.json file. There you can edit the color codes using it's property.

File looks like this-> [image]

Property to be used:-

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme]": {
      "dart.closingLabels": "#335566"
    }
  }
```

Comment: OKay. I got that one. But what is the property name for the specified texts(The red marked in my pic) That is the problem I face.

Comment: I've added the property. check it @ameen

Comment: Thank you so much man! That worked. How did you find the property?

Comment: I've read it in vs code theme documentation.. if you like my solution please vote up.

Comment: I've read it in vs code theme documentation.. if you like my solution please vote up.

Comment: When I vote up it shows a message - " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded,..."

Comment: Hello @ShikharSingh, Can you tell me which theme are you using in this screenshot?